# Python: Taking frequencies from a song

Tags: python, frequency

I'm writing a code for making a light show with 4 bulb, they will switch their combinations according to a song. Therefore, i have to take frequency of a song. I found this code and it is basicly what i want.

```
# Read in a WAV and find the freq's
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np

chunk = 2024

# open up a wave
wf = wave.open('Audio_3.wav', 'rb')
swidth = wf.getsampwidth()
RATE = wf.getframerate()
# use a Blackman window
window = np.blackman(chunk)
# open stream
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format =
                p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels = wf.getnchannels(),
                rate = RATE,
                output = True)

# read some data
data = wf.readframes(chunk)
# play stream and find the frequency of each chunk
print(len(data))
print(chunk*swidth)
while len(data) == chunk*swidth:
    # write data out to the audio stream
    stream.write(data)
    # unpack the data and times by the hamming window
    indata = np.array(wave.struct.unpack("%dh"%(len(data)/swidth),\
                                         data))*window
    # Take the fft and square each value
    fftData=abs(np.fft.rfft(indata))**2
    # find the maximum
    which = fftData[1:].argmax() + 1
    # use quadratic interpolation around the max
    if which != len(fftData)-1:
        y0,y1,y2 = np.log(fftData[which-1:which+2:])
        x1 = (y2 - y0) * .5 / (2 * y1 - y2 - y0)
        # find the frequency and output it
        thefreq = (which+x1)*RATE/chunk
        print ("The freq is %f Hz." % (thefreq))
    else:
        thefreq = which*RATE/chunk
        print ("The freq is %f Hz." % (thefreq))
    # read some more data
    data = wf.readframes(chunk)
if data:
    stream.write(data)
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

However, the problem is this code just working for basic sounds. When i tried this code for a song while loop is turning false. Is there any code for taking frequency from a song? Or any other way?

Comment: You mean you're trying to calculate the tempo of the song in beats per minute? That's a non-trivial problem.

Comment: what's the len(data) that you get printed? Are the basic sounds that it works for, and the songs it doesnt work for, in the same format? Maybe the songs are too long to handle for whatever reason?

Comment: @SimonN Well i think if take frequency, i may find note and give every note a light combination for switch them

Comment: @jeremy_rutman len(data) printed 8096 and chunck*switch printed 4048. I tried with short ones but its not made any different.

Comment: For the 'basic sounds' the loop runs so chunk*swidth=len(data) at some point, maybe there's some problem with the sample .  For instance maybe you have 2 channels in your basic sounds and 1 channel in your music files?

Answer (score 1):

I think the stereo files were causing trouble, as the data size will ultimately be the sample width * num_samples * num_channels. The following seems to work , giving a consistent 433+-1Hz for a 440Hz tone as generated by audacity (the error either coming from the fft or from audacity's generator)

```
# Read in a WAV and find the freq's
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np

chunk = 1024

# open up a wave

wf = wave.open('/home/jeremy/Music/wav1.wav', 'rb')
swidth = wf.getsampwidth()
RATE = wf.getframerate()
# use a Blackman window
window = np.blackman(chunk)
# open stream
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
channels = wf.getnchannels()
stream = p.open(format =
                p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels = channels,
                rate = RATE,
                output = True)

# read some data
data = wf.readframes(chunk)
# play stream and find the frequency of each chunk
print('switdth {} chunk {} data {} ch {}'.format(swidth,chunk,len(data), channels))
while len(data) == chunk*swidth*channels:
    # write data out to the audio stream
    stream.write(data)
    # unpack the data and times by the hamming window
#    indata = np.array(wave.struct.unpack("%dh"%(len(data)/(swidth)),data))*window
    indata = np.fromstring(data, dtype='int16')
    # deinterleave, select 1 channel
    channel0 = indata[0::channels]

    # Take the fft and square each value
    fftData=abs(np.fft.rfft(indata))**2
    # find the maximum
    which = fftData[1:].argmax() + 1
    # use quadratic interpolation around the max
    if which != len(fftData)-1:
        y0,y1,y2 = np.log(fftData[which-1:which+2:])
        x1 = (y2 - y0) * .5 / (2 * y1 - y2 - y0)
        # find the frequency and output it
        thefreq = (which+x1)*RATE/chunk
        print ("The freq is %f Hz." % (thefreq))
    else:
        thefreq = which*RATE/chunk
        print ("The freq is %f Hz." % (thefreq))
    # read some more data
    data = wf.readframes(chunk)
if data:
    stream.write(data)
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```